# Obtener URL completa del href

Tags: javascript, jquery, href

Tengo el siguiente código que al presionar un `<a href` obtengo la url de este mismo:

```
<a href="http://localhost/uno/dos.zip">DESCARGAR</a>
```

y jQuery

```
$('a').click(function(event) {
  var url = $('a').attr('href');
  alert(url);
});
```

El problema es el siguiente: cuando presiono el link en la página index.php que estoy haciendo, este al presionar se ejecuta la función del jQuery que me muestra una url, pero esta función toma solo el valor de http://localhost y no la url entera http://localhost/uno/dos.zip que está en el `<a href` de más arriba.

¿Existe alguna otra opción a parte de href?

Comment: La verdad no entendí casi nada, ¿Que quieres hacer?

Comment: edita la redacción que hay algo enredado ahí , como que presionas **http://localhost**, eso es una ruta no un botón,  te da algún error? , que te da y que deseas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Revisa tu código porque con el que pones debería aparecerte la url completa.

Aquí tienes el ejemplo funcionando:

```js
$('a').click(function(event) {
  var url = $('a').attr('href');
  alert(url);
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>

<a href="http://localhost/uno/dos">DESCARGAR</a>
```

Comment: Puede que sea porque estoy usando la libreria jquery.3.2.1.slim.min.js

Comment: He modificado el ejemplo para utilizar la misma versión de jQuery y, como verás, también funciona sin problemas. El error tiene que estar en otra parte.

Comment: aquí tu ejemplo me funciona de maravillas, realize el copy paste para ver si era algun error de tipeo y sigo con el mismo problema, debe ser el codegniter que me debe estar bloqueando lo que estoy mostrando, porque es un post que viene de la base de datos. revisare bien detenidamente cual sera el problema, hice la prueba fuera de codegniter y funciona de maravillas tu código.

Comment: ya encontré el problema, resulta que el código solo toma el primer <a href que se encuentra en la página y no el que presiono. antes de este link <a href hay como 10 más. Me entendió Asier Villanueva.